# How do I convert bitcoins into Brazilian currency?

Tags: exchanges, sell-bitcoins

I have a Bitcoin wallet for a mobile device. How can I convert bitcoins into Brazilian currency?

Comment: @Geremia no idea how to vote but I'm voting on that too!

Answer (score 1):

To find an exchange in Brasil you can try [buybitcoinworldwide.com](https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/). There are many exchanges, the site does not list all of them.

Most exchanges that let you buy bitcoins also let you sell (for a fee of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate that in mind easily!!

1 BTC equals $10,000. $10,000 equals 45346523136 BR.